# Language specific url rewriting in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url-rewriting

I am trying to rebuild a web forms project in mvc 4.

Not relly an expert, but I understand basic of routing in MVC. What i want to know is how to hanndle this example.

In webforms I had

```
http://www.site.com/en/4039/vehicle-Mazda3-year-2011.aspx
http://www.site.com/fr/4039/voiture-Mazda3-annee-2011.aspx
```

and base page for all of it was actually

```
http://www.site.com/container/car.aspx?ID=4309
```

Now in MVC I could have

```
http://www.site.com/en/cars/4039
http://www.site.com/fr/cars/4039
```

but not really sure how i can add dynamically generated part of the url to make it language friendly, something like

```
http://www.site.com/en/vehicles/4039/vehicle-Mazda3-year-2011/
http://www.site.com/fr/voitures/4039/voiture-Mazda3-annee-2011/
```

Comment: in your maproute , second argument should have {controller}/{language}/{action}/{others} , then you can build your constraint in fourth argument which checks for language equals to en or fr or whatever...

Comment: @sharma sure but how to generate this dynamic url?

Comment: i guess , its part of the link you are building in your view , routing has nothing to do here..can you explain a bit how you've dealed with it in asp.net

Comment: @vishalsharma i used Response.Filter to override urls in output html

Comment: ok so in that case what you can do is complete your route as i explain .. create a filter or base controller override before action executing Method and rewrite your url from getting inputs from requestcontext , and finally do redirecttoaction/redirectpermanently to show your url to browser..

Comment: @vishalsharma do you have an example or link for this to help me better understand it?

Comment: sure.... wait for sometime.....

Comment: hey john , take a look at http://www.wiliam.com.au/wiliam-blog/web-design-sydney-using-mvc-routing-for-seo-friendly-urls-on-multilingual-sites  , :)